# gender of 'one' in the sentence 'one of the [something]'

Tags: gender

From Google translate, the sentence

> he is one of the members

should be translated to

> er ist eines der Mitglieder

Why do we use 'eines' here? How do we determine the gender of 'one'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The gender of the indefinite pronoun needs to align with the gender of the corelated noun, here "Mitglied", thus neuter.

- eine der Frauen
- einer der Männer
- eines der Kinder

Comment: It might help to explain why the correlated noun is not 'er' here. For example if you translate 'He is one of them' the result is 'Er ist einer von ihnen' correlating 'einer' with 'er'. Why is there a gender change between the two sentences?